# Is there is any limitation of a html page

Tags: html

Is there is any limitation of a html page that it can only hold some kb of data. if we do rest code it will be ignored.

Comment: Not really, but there are all sorts of limits (the amount of RAM of the machine the browser runs on, for example) in practice.  If you give a little more information about what you're trying to do you might actually get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the [HTTP protocol is concerned](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13), the content-length header field defines the size of the content, which can be any value greater than or equal to 0.

But you've got to consider limitations on bandwidth, transfer time, memory, etc.. The size of a web page should never be more than manageable anyway. Do you really want to be delivering a page that's so big you're having to question whether there's a limit?

Answer (score 0):

If your page is too big, it will take too long to load and users will cancel the load and leave before it finishes.  If it's *really* too big, the browser will run out of memory and crash.  "too big" and "really too big" are relative terms, and different for every user.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, your only limit is what you set Content-length to be in the response header (apart from things like how much memory your browser can use, how many bytes you can transfer over the network before the apocalypse, etc.).